# Derivative of a 3D Interpolated function

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, interpolation

I cannot get the partial derivative of a set of data. I managed to get the accurate interpolation, but I cannot evaluate its derivatives.

Here are my details:

```
data = Import["data.dat"];
```

The data set looks like this:

```
In[]=
data[[38;;49]]

Out[]=
{ 
{2, 38, -0.000307893533656}, 
{2, 39, -0.000307922246488},
{2, 40, -0.000307952337061}, 
{3, 0, -0.000461750353095},
{3, 1, -0.000462600240141}, 
{3, 2, -0.000463450127186}, 
{3, 3, -0.000464294338731},
{3, 4, -0.000464294338731}
}
```

The 3D Interpolation looks good:

```
 pot = Interpolation[data]
```

[image]

And the Plot3D does too:

```
ListPlot3D[data, ColorFunction -> "SouthwestColors"]
```

[image]

There is a slight change along y (unnoticeable from Plot3D), I want to get the derivative for this function (which is along y):

```
Plot[ pot[50, y], {y, 0, 40} ]
```

[image]

When I use `Derivative` I get this, unable to even extract a value:

```
 pot'[50, y]
 pot'[50,3]
```

[image]
[image]

Not getting a function at all...

```
 Plot[pot'[50, y], {y, 0, 40}]
```

[image]

What is the smart way to get the gradient of the 3D interpolated function? I also tried 'Gradient' without success:

```
Gradient[pot[x, y]]
VectorPlot[Gradient[pot[x, y]], {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 40}]
```

[image]

**What must I do?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Derivative[0, 1][int]` to get the first derivative of `int` with respect to your second variable $y$.

To illustrate, let's create some data and interpolate:

```
data = Table[{x, y, Sin[x] + 2 y}, {x, 0., 10.}, {y, 0., 10.}] ~ Flatten ~ 1;
int = Interpolation[data];

Plot3D[int[x, y], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}]
```

[image: 3D plot of function]

Then obtain the first derivative with respect to x vs. y respectively, and compare them with he expected values (i.e. `Cos[x]` and $2$, respectively):

```
Plot[
  {
    Derivative[1, 0][int][x, 3],
    Cos[x]
  },
  {x, 0, 10}
]
```

[image: plot of 1st derivative wrt x compared to cos(x)]

Note that the jumps in the interpolation above are due to the relatively coarse grid on which the interpolation was carried out (i.e. with spacings of only 1 unit). This doesn't matter much here since it's just a made-up example; indeed, in a way it helps to show the two functions separately.

```
Plot[
  {
    Derivative[0, 1][int][Pi, y],
    2
  },
  {y, 0, 10}
]
```

[image: plot of 1st derivative wrt y compared to the constant 2]

Comment: Incredible, very illustrative example. Appreciate your time!

Comment: @Joshua Glad to help!